# Angular app doesn't display a page if no refresh

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm working on an Angular app. The issue is that if I first access the app with a cleared cache and local storage, the app doesn't display its pages until I refresh the browser on time.

How can I fix that?

Comment: we need at least errors or some code parts! 
please check the templates you are using that can cause errors too 
Check the console for errors